# Search is not throwing any result

Tags: search

It is Drupal 7.

This is kind of strange behaviour of the website.

This is my website http://www.protecdental.com. If you visit this website, you will see the right-hand top search field. Please see the screenshot https://snag.gy/LfCDxs.jpg

If you type any junk keyword (That means the site will definitely throw 0 results) for example "werewe" then you will see the proper search result page with no result.

But if you type a keyword related to the website's content for example "dental" or "contact" or any related meaning full keyword then you will see the broken page with no content at all.

Not too sure the issues is: it seems like if there is a search result data, then it is somehow breaking the page:

I didn't find any error log for it even when I tried watchdog.

- I cleared the cache
- I re-indexed the search
- I manually ran the cron

But no luck. Can anyone please help to at least narrow down the cause of this issue.

## My default search result template:

```
<?php if ($search_results): ?>
    <h2><?php print t('Search results');?></h2>
    <ol class="search-results <?php print $module; ?>-results">
        <?php print $search_results; ?>
    </ol>
    <?php print $pager; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <h2><?php print t('Your search yielded no results');?></h2>
    <?php print search_help('search#noresults', drupal_help_arg()); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Put this in your settings.php file and see if you can get something useful. $conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;

Comment: @cchen thank you for your quick response. I uncommented it in my settings.php file but didn't get any error message

Comment: You are welcome. Do you have a custom template for the search result page? If so I'd double check the php syntax in the template.

Comment: @cchen How to check for it? as i didnt initially build this and trying to find the solution.

Comment: You can check it in two ways. 1 use inspect element with 'theme_debug' on, and you should be able to see the active template's name and location of the search results section. 2. go to your custom theme's directory and look for something like `search-results.tpl.php`

Comment: @cchen this site is not using a custom template for search but this is a code from the default template. I have added a code in my main post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84508/discussion-between-cchen-and-mak).

Comment: @cchen this issues is fixed. when i checked the search-results template file, i saw weird string on top of the page i removed it and it fixed the issues. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem, yeah when you see an error page like that, most of time the issue is in one of the template files.